# Is there a (non-jailbroken) iPhone app that works like Android Lock?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

Is there an app which works like [Andriod Lock](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/security/how-to-enable-pattern-lock-security-on-android-devices/) on IPhone. I had read cydia offers
but on jailbreak. Is there an official one for this.

Comment: i had read an article here http://www.gadgetvenue.com/android-lock-iphone-01295947/

Comment: The Cydia version of AndroidLock does not work on iOS4, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, there's no official, Apple-approved replacement for the lock screen.** If you really want to use Android Lock, you must jailbreak and then install it via Cydia.

Un-jailbroken phones can only do what Apple allows, which is to run one app at a time. *Android Lock* is different because what it does is to *modify* the basic system of the phone, which Apple doesn't allow. And that is the reason why such apps or modifications are only available on jailbroken phones (through Cydia, the jailbroken appstore).